# How to Two Tables And One Login Form To Log In

Tags: php, mysql

Please help,I have a major doubt: Could you please help me with this
How can I SELECT all data from two differences table and login in username & userpassword in one login form?

```
$loginEmail = $_POST['loginEmail'];
$loginPassword = $_POST['loginPassword'];
$corpStaffNo = $_POST['corpStaffNo'];
$corpHRDF = $_POST['corpHRDF'];
$corpContact = $_POST['corpContact'];
$corEmail = $_POST['corEmail'];
$corpFax = $_POST['corpFax'];

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ABC");
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_member, corp_member WHERE loginEmail='$loginEmail' AND loginPassword='$loginPassword'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
   alert('sdcsv');
   window.location.replace(\"http:://localhost\");
   </script>";
} else {
   echo "your login";
}
```

Comment: are you having store user_id in corp_member table ?

Comment: Have you tried using a JOIN? Do you have a foreign key? FYI SQL Injection is going on your way

Comment: Side-remark: to redirect in PHP, use [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: @sagarpatel, user_id & corp_member are two difference table.

Comment: @ClaudioPinto, yes I tried JOIN but not working.

Comment: @Mikey, i want to login. how to use header() to solve this problem?

Comment: @Fun header will only help you redirect the user to a different page. To login you will need to retrieve the user data from the database and then store some kind of session object in the session. I'll leave and example as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use a JOIN statement and have a foreign key (soft or hard your choice).

let's say that the user_member table has a columns named corp_id and the corp_name table has a column named id

```
$result = $comm->query("SELECT u.* FROM user_member AS u JOIN corp_member AS c ON u.corp_id = c.id WHERE loginEmail='$loginEmail' AND loginPassword='$loginPassword';");
```

then you can redirect using header

```
if (!$row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   header('location: /');
} else {
   $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
   header('location: /logedin');
}

//good idea to exit to force the redirect and prevent further execution
exit;
```

FYI: I didn't do any [SQL escaping](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) you should really do that.

FYI2: By the naming of the tables it feels like corp_member is a relational table most likely there will be another table name corp. if that is the case the query will probably look more like this

```mysql
SELECT u.*, c.* FROM user_member AS u
JOIN corp_member AS cm ON cm.id = cm.user_member_id
JOIN corp AS c ON cm.corp_id = c.id
```